# NuGet Framework package with dependencies from Core project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, packagereference

I am trying to reference from a .NET Core 3.1 project, a NuGet package that targets only `net40` via the NuGet compatibility shim. The package is added to my project, however the `net40` dependencies are not.

The package is structured as:

```
lib\
  net40\
    AssemblyA.dll

nuspec: 
  <dependencies>
    <group targetFramework="net40">
      <dependency id="PackageB" version="1.0" />
    </group>
  </dependencies>
```

Visual Studio's Package Manager lists the dependencies, but when installed, the dependencies are not listed by VS' Preview Changes window and are indeed not installed. `PackageB` also targets `net40`.

It does work if I:

- Include the dependencies in an "Any" (blank) dependency group as well as under `net40`
- Remove the `net40` dependency group and list the package directly under `<dependencies>` as a flat list
- Remove the `net40` under `lib\` and use a flat list

These are not ideal as it obfuscates the true nature of the targets frameworks. The last two produce `NU5128` on `pack`. For future reference, I should mention that it's required to remove the dependencies from the local cache for even these scenarios to work (surely a bug?).

Any ideas on how to pull dependencies from such packages? Is this simply not supported? A good test example of this is the "Polly.Net40Async" package.

(VS: 16.6.5, dotnet: 3.1.302, PackageReference, Windows 10)

Comment: It's a bug in NuGet, but it hasn't got enough upvotes to be prioritized: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5957

Comment: @zivkan, Thanks for the link, indeed it looks like a bug. It appears the keyword I was missing in my fruitless googling on this was "AssetTargetFallback".

(aside) Who would downvote this question???

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to reference from a .NET Core 3.1 project, a NuGet package
> that targets only net40 via the NuGet compatibility shim. The package
> is added to my project, however the net40 dependencies are not.

The nuget package only targets to `net40` which means the package is used for `net framework 4+`.

**And by default**, Net Core projects cannot use this type of nuget unless the package and dependencies are listed as supporting **Net Core** or **Net Standard**.

==========================================

**Also**, you can notice the info from the [Polly.Net40Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Net40Async/5.9.0?_src=template) nuget package:

[image]

`group targetFramework="net40"` means that if your project **targetframework** version is `4+`, it will install the listed dependencies.

**So** you should not install this type of packages into `Net Core 3.1` project. And it is designed by the author.

**Besides**, if you change the sub folder of **lib** in the nuget package to `any`, you can add the dependencies into the **Net Core** project.

**After all**, `any` means it targets to any framework versions--`net core`, `net standard`, `net framework`. And you just need to remove the condition of the dependency (contention on `Net Framework 4+`).

====================================

**Add more detailed info**

**Update 1**

**Actually**, Net Core projects can install some nuget packages which only targets to Net Framework.

**In my side**, the package can be installed in the Net Core project.**However**, there is a warning which shows it may not be fully compatible with your **Net Core** project. **Although** you can use it, there are still some problems just not encountered in special situations.

For the dependencies, since your project targets to **Net Core** rather than **Net Framework**, the dependencies will not be installed automatically along with the main package. But you can manually install these dependencies separately through **Nuget Package Manager UI**.(search them and then install them one by one).

**And** if condition `group targetFramework="net40"` is met, it will install these dependencies automatically along with the main nuget package. But since your project targets to **Net Core**, it will not install them automatically.

**As a suggestion**, you could search these dependencies on the **Nuget Package Manager UI**, and then manually install them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I respectfully disagree. Support for taking a .NET Framework reference from a .NET Core project is explicitly supported. In my specific case, the Framework API's I'm using from Core are 100% compatible, however, the rest of the API may not be. I feel that it would be wrong to ask a package owner to falsely advertise a package as fully supporting either Core or 'any' target as a workaround to this bug. For now as a workaround, the package's dependencies can be directly referenced by the Core project.

Comment: `Sorry for not providing enough detailed info first. ` Actually, net core projects can install net framework nuget packages. However, it will turn out a warning: compatibility problem.Although it can be used, there may be problems in some special situations. And since your project targets to `Net Core` rather than `net40`,  the condition is false and it will not install the dependencies automatically along with the main project. So you will not see the dependencies on your project as you described before.

Comment: `As a suggestion`, you should search them one by one on the` Nuget package manager` and then install them manually. And then your project can find all of them.

Comment: I have supplemented the detailed info in my answer and  you can check it:)